# Local server works in firefox, treated as search in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

When I try to access my client page via:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

Firefox renders the page but chrome treats it as a search. Any fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 127.0.0.1 rather than 0.0.0.0 -- I'm not convinced that 0.0.0.0 is actually a standard address for localhost, and since it's less common than 127.0.0.1 it stands to reason that some browsers may not redirect it.